# How can i make systemcall and user function in Ubuntu xv6?

Tags: c, ubuntu, xv6

I'm a student.
I have to Make System Calls

- int getreadcount(void)
- Returns the value of a counter which is incremented every time any
  process calls the read() system call.
- Make a user program readcount using getreadcount()
  system call for testin

so I did that.

user.h:

```
int getreadcount(void)
```

usys.S:

```
SYSCALL(getreadcount)
```

syscall.c:

```
extern int sys_getreadcount(void);
[SYS_getreadcount] sys_getreadcount
```

sysfile.c:

```
int count = 0;
count ++ //in sys_read
```

[sysfile.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYj8P.png) <- when read function run, count variable++

`//proc.h int count;`   (<- GPT order)

`//sysproc.c`
[sysproc.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKiEw.png)

`//readcout.c`
[readcount.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPk5P.png)
The error was not corrected even if it was changed to `printf(2, "%d", count);` here.

`makefile`
[makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHtBz.png)

than when i called readcount in xv6,
`trap 14 err 5 on cpu 1 eip 0xffffffff addr 0xffffffff--kill proc`
[xv6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd21j.png)
....
What did I do wrong?

Please understand that I am a college student who is just learning computers, so I lack related knowledge, and I expressed it awkwardly because I am not an English speaker. I've been thinking about it for a few days, but I haven't got an answer, so I'm asking experts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your code as formatted text into the question. This applies to all text: code, input, output, expected output, error messages, makefiles, Commands to build or run your program etc..

Comment: BTW, I don't think this should have the `ubuntu` tag, as the question is related only to xv6 ( the x86 port to be precise)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you are missing is calling `exit()` at the end of readcount main function, this will invoke the exit syscall which is the right way to exit a process in xv6.

Here is the full patch with the change I suggested (and including your changes for convenience) :

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 09d790c..30b0e1e 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -176,6 +176,7 @@ UPROGS=\
        _ls\
        _mkdir\
        _rm\
+       _readcount\
        _sh\
        _stressfs\
        _usertests\
diff --git a/readcount.c b/readcount.c
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..78a29a0
--- /dev/null
+++ b/readcount.c
@@ -0,0 +1,9 @@
+#include "types.h"
+#include "stat.h"
+#include "user.h"
+
+int main(void) {
+    int count = getreadcount();
+    printf(1, "%d\n", count);
+    exit();
+}
diff --git a/syscall.c b/syscall.c
index ee85261..bcd18ef 100644
--- a/syscall.c
+++ b/syscall.c
@@ -103,6 +103,7 @@ extern int sys_unlink(void);
 extern int sys_wait(void);
 extern int sys_write(void);
 extern int sys_uptime(void);
+extern int sys_getreadcount(void);

 static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
 [SYS_fork]    sys_fork,
@@ -126,6 +127,7 @@ static int (*syscalls[])(void) = {
 [SYS_link]    sys_link,
 [SYS_mkdir]   sys_mkdir,
 [SYS_close]   sys_close,
+[SYS_getreadcount] sys_getreadcount
 };

 void
diff --git a/syscall.h b/syscall.h
index bc5f356..a12d885 100644
--- a/syscall.h
+++ b/syscall.h
@@ -20,3 +20,4 @@
 #define SYS_link   19
 #define SYS_mkdir  20
 #define SYS_close  21
+#define SYS_getreadcount  22
diff --git a/sysfile.c b/sysfile.c
index bfe61b7..40db318 100644
--- a/sysfile.c
+++ b/sysfile.c
@@ -66,13 +66,15 @@ sys_dup(void)
   return fd;
 }

+static int count = 0;
+
 int
 sys_read(void)
 {
   struct file *f;
   int n;
   char *p;
-
+  count++;
   if(argfd(0, 0, &f) < 0 || argint(2, &n) < 0 || argptr(1, &p, n) < 0)
     return -1;
   return fileread(f, p, n);
@@ -442,3 +444,9 @@ sys_pipe(void)
   fd[1] = fd1;
   return 0;
 }
+
+int
+sys_getreadcount(void)
+{
+    return count;
+}
diff --git a/user.h b/user.h
index 4f99c52..7886468 100644
--- a/user.h
+++ b/user.h
@@ -23,6 +23,7 @@ int getpid(void);
 char* sbrk(int);
 int sleep(int);
 int uptime(void);
+int getreadcount(void);

 // ulib.c
 int stat(const char*, struct stat*);
diff --git a/usys.S b/usys.S
index 8bfd8a1..7af84de 100644
--- a/usys.S
+++ b/usys.S
@@ -29,3 +29,4 @@ SYSCALL(getpid)
 SYSCALL(sbrk)
 SYSCALL(sleep)
 SYSCALL(uptime)
+SYSCALL(getreadcount)
```